# Apply 'rlike' on a regex column?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I'm looking to apply the 'rlike' function on a column, however instead of a standard regular expression string I want to be able to input a column (which is a regular expression string).

ie. `$col1.rlike($col2)`
where $col2 is in a regular expression format within the dataframe

I have tried applying a UDF:
`def rLike = udf((s: String, col: Column) => col.rlike(s))`

This keeps giving me the error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported

Could anyone please shed some light on how I can fix this.

Comment: Changing `col: Column` to `col: String` should work. The column type is a string so that is the correct input type to an udf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method [`rlike`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@rlike(literal:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) does not support regex-matching pattern stored in a `Column`.  An alternative is to use [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@regexp_replace(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,replacement:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("a123", "[a-z]\\d+"),
  ("b456", "[a-z]+")
).toDF("text", "pattern")

val matched = "Matched!"  // can be any value non-existent in column `text`

df.where(regexp_replace($"text", $"pattern", lit(matched)) === matched).show
// +----+--------+
// |text| pattern|
// +----+--------+
// |a123|[a-z]\d+|
// +----+--------+
```

In case you would like to implement a custom `rlike` as an UDF (which generally doesn't scale well compared with native Spark API functions), here's one way:

```
def rlike = udf( (text: String, pattern: String) => text match {
  case pattern.r() => true
  case _ => false
} )

// Applying the UDF
df.where(rlike($"text", $"pattern"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The original question was answered in a comment: the UDF needs to be implemented with the signature `(s: String, col: String): Boolean`

For anyone else who stumbled upon this question -- without using a UDF, the only semi-clean way I could find to do this as of now is to use `expr` function.

```
df.where(expr("col1 RLIKE col2"))
```

I found one Jira issue([SPARK-11366](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11366)) requesting functions such as `rlike` to accept other columns, but it seems to have been closed without updates.